# Setting transparent background for JCheckbox without changing background color of JPanel using java swing

Tags: java, swing

In Java I have created a `JCheckBox` and set it's opaque to false and added that checkbox to a panel. After execution whenever I'm taking the cursor on that checkbox, the checkboxes glitched background is appearing which is annoying.

Any solution?

I created panel with this proerties:

```
setLayout(null);
setBounds(210, 75, 1301, 750);
setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,175));
```

Created checkbox:

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Morning");
checkBox.setBounds(500, 300, 100, 30);
checkBox.setOpaque(false);
checkBox.setForeground(Color.white);
checkBox.setFont(new Font("DialogInput", Font.BOLD, 16));
checkBox.setFocusable(false);
add(checkBox);
```

Comment: Swing doesn't support alpha based colors - you have to fake it.

Comment: Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for a solution that doesn't require custom painting.

Answer (score 1):

Swing doesn't support alpha/translucent colors, only fully opaque colors, instead, you need to fake it.

[image]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
            TransparentCheckBox cb = new TransparentCheckBox();
            cb.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            cb.setAlpha(0.5f);
            add(cb);
        }

    }

    public class TransparentCheckBox extends JCheckBox {

        private float alpha = 1.0f;

        public TransparentCheckBox() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public float getAlpha() {
            return alpha;
        }

        public void setAlpha(float aplha) {
            this.alpha = aplha;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(getAlpha()));
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

    }
}
```